# Proof that $\binom p k \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for certain $k$

Tags: combinations

How would you go about proving that
$$
{p \choose k} \equiv 0 \pmod p
$$
if $0 < k < p$ and $p$ is prime?

**Edit:** I'm fairly certain that I should begin at the definition of the binomial coefficient, namely that
$$
{p \choose k} = \frac{p!}{(p - k)! \cdot k!}
$$
and rewrite it as
$$
\frac{p \cdot (p - 1)!}{(p - k)! \cdot k!} = p \cdot \frac{(p - 1)!}{(p - k)! \cdot k!}
$$
which shows that it is a multiple of $p$ and thus equivalent to zero modulo $p$. However, I know that this is not complete and I am unsure of what to do next.

Comment: You're in the right way, becuase you get  p*X where X is the fraction next to p. All it's left is to show that X is integer and you finished

Comment: How would you show that $X$ is an integer for $0 < k < p$ though?

Comment: It isn’t true if $p=4$, say; did you mean to specify that $p$ is prime?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that. Yes, we are allowed to assume that $p$ is prime. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: One could also use induction

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\binom{p}k=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}\;;$$ if $0<k<p$, how many factors of $p$ are there in the denominator? Remember, $p$ is prime.

Comment: I don't see what you mean...

Comment: @Matthew: There’s clearly a factor of $p$ in the numerator; you found that yourself. Look at $k!$: it’s $k(k-1)(k-2)\ldots(2)(1)$. Is any of the numbers $k,k-1,\ldots,2,1$ divisible by $p$?

Comment: No, none of them are divisible by $p$ because $k < p$.

Comment: @Matthew: and because $k>0$, no factor of $(n-k)!$ is divisible by $p$. So can the denominator contain any factors of $p$ at all$?

Comment: No? I don't think so...

Comment: @Matthew: That’s right: it can’t. If $p$ were composite it could: you could get a factor of $6$, for instance, from $2!4!$. But when $p$ is prime, that can’t happen: if it’s a factor of a product, it must divide one of the factors forming that product. $k!(n-k)!$ has no factor divisible by $p$, so **is** isn’t divisible by $p$ either.