# Prove that this expression is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Prove that

$$
\frac{(p - 1)!}{(p - k)! \cdot k!} 
$$

is an integer if $0 < k < p$ and $p$ is prime.

Comment: Any ideas? Tried anything? Show your work so far.

Comment: Yes, master, I finished my proof of that. What shall you command I do next?

Comment: I've tried a few things but can someone just give me an answer? This isn't a homework problem - just an example from my textbook that I'm failing to understand.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Use [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528115/12042) and the fact that $$\frac{(p - 1)!}{(p - k)! \cdot k!}=\frac1p\binom{p}k\;.$$