# $ {q \choose m} = 0$, for all $m = 1, ..., q-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $F$ a field with $\operatorname{char}F\mid q$, then $\displaystyle {q \choose m} = 0$, for all $m = 1, ..., q-1$.

*Comments:* I'm trying to decompose q into product of primes.

Comment: *Hint*: the characteristic of a field is either $0$ or a prime number $p$.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528115/proof-that-binom-p-k-equiv-0-pmod-p-for-certain-k).